# Deploy on aws failed, because of AWSEBLoadBalancer doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, awsdeploy

I have a app deployed on aws, which works fine for months, and the last time I deployed it is a month ago, and I have no trouble at that time. But when I did my deploy process yesterday, I got the error "AWSEBLoadBalancer doesn't exist". But in my aws admin loadbalancer page, it shows I do have a loadbalancer, now I don't know what's going on.

Error messages:

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
ERROR: "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
ERROR: Load Balancer ListenerEnabled setting cannot be applied because AWSEBLoadBalancer doesn't exist. 
ERROR: Load Balancer CrossZone setting cannot be applied because AWSEBLoadBalancer doesn't exist. 
ERROR: Load Balancer ConnectionDrainingEnabled setting cannot be applied because AWSEBLoadBalancer doesn't exist. 
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Any one can help me?

I am using ElasticBeanstalk, by the way.

Comment: What service are you using? OpsWorks? ElasticBeanstalk?

Comment: @ George M Whitaker ti's ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: I wonder if some of the tags that are written on the ELB by Beanstalk have gotten modified. I think that's how it knows what resources to interact with, but this is a wild guess.

Comment: Did you ever figure out where this error is coming from?  I'm currently receiving it as a config error for my cloudformation script. I'm attempting to set up a beanstalk app that uses HTTPS instead of the default protocol. Configuring the OptionSettings for this protocol within the configuration template is throwing the same error you're seeing. I tried separately creating an ELB that is configured properly, but there doesn't appear to be a way to attach it to the beanstalk environment.

Comment: @DGaffneyDC see the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a configure mistake, one of my colleagues changed the Classic Load Balancer to Application Load Balancer, and some configure files did't adopt to this change, that's why we get this error.

It's weird this error did't emerge early, because this change has been made almost a month ago before we receive the error.And we did't make any changes after that.